# SQL - Getting working days of date range within another date range

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 Sets for Date Ranges :

1. `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` : Being passed to a stored procedure
2. `ProjectStartDate` and `ProjectEndDate` : In the Database

The goal is to get the number of working days (public holidays are ignored) that `ProjectStartDate` and `ProjectEndDate` fall between `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`.

Example 1:

```
@StartDate = 2016/03/21
@EndDate = 2016/03/25

ProjectStartDate = 2016/03/13
ProjectEndDate = 2016/03/22
```

So the number of working days I need to work out are where `ProjectStartDate` and `ProjectEndDate` fall beween `@StartDate` and `@Endate` - in this case, number of working days would be 2(Mon - Fri)

Example 2 :

```
ProjectStartDate = 2016/03/22
ProjectEndDate = 2016/03/29
```

So the number of working days I need to work out are where `ProjectStartDate` and `ProjectEndDate` fall between `@StartDate` and `@Endate` - in this case, number of working days would be 4(Mon - Fri)

Example 3 :

```
ProjectStartDate = 2016/03/13
ProjectEndDate = 2016/03/29
```

So the number of working days I need to work out are where `ProjectStartDate` and `ProjectEndDate` fall between `@StartDate` and `@Endate` - in this case, number of working days would be 5(Mon - Fri)

The code I have to work out the working days is as follows :

```
(DATEDIFF(dd, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart), ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualEnd,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedEnd)) + 1)
       -(DATEDIFF(wk, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart), ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualEnd,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedEnd)) * 2)
       -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart)) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart)) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

I have tried to get the result, but it partially works. I know there is a simpler way of doing this :

```
CASE WHEN(CASE WHEN @StartDate <= ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart) 
       THEN (DATEDIFF(dd, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart), @EndDate) + 1)
       -(DATEDIFF(wk, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart), @EndDate) * 2)
       -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart)) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart)) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
       ELSE (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualEnd,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedEnd)) + 1)
       -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualEnd,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedEnd)) * 2)
       -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END) >= 5 
       THEN 5           
       ELSE (CASE WHEN @StartDate <= ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart) 
       THEN (DATEDIFF(dd, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart), @EndDate) + 1)
       -(DATEDIFF(wk, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart), @EndDate) * 2)
       -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart)) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart)) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
       ELSE (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualEnd,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedEnd)) + 1)
       -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualEnd,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedEnd)) * 2)
       -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END) END AS DaysCalculated
```

Comment: Based on your Sql syntax I've removed the MySql Tag.

Comment: any chance that the input `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` will include Sat, Sun ?

Comment: @Squirrel, In my case, StartDate and EndDate will always be the Monday and Friday.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up finding the answer, it seems. I would prefer to find a cleaner, neater way... but I cant spend more time on this and this works for now. If Anyone has a cleaner, neater option, please let me know. Thanks.

```
(CASE WHEN ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart) >= @StartDate AND 
                 ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualEnd,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedEnd) >= @EndDate
            THEN
               (DATEDIFF(dd, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart), @EndDate) + 1)
               -(DATEDIFF(wk, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart), @EndDate) * 2)
               -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart)) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
               -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart)) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
            ELSE 
                (CASE WHEN ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart) >= @StartDate AND
                          ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualEnd,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedEnd) <= @EndDate 
                THEN
                    (DATEDIFF(dd, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart), ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualEnd,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedEnd)) + 1)
                   -(DATEDIFF(wk, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart), ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualEnd,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedEnd)) * 2)
                   -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart)) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                   -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart)) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                ELSE
                    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart) <= @StartDate AND
                          ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualEnd,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedEnd) <= @EndDate 
                     THEN
                        (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualEnd,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedEnd)) + 1)
                       -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualEnd,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedEnd)) * 2)
                       -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                       -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                     ELSE
                        (CASE WHEN ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualStart,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedStart) <= @StartDate AND
                          ISNULL(AA.DDAreaActivityActualEnd,AA.DDAreaActivityPlannedEnd) >= @EndDate 
                         THEN
                            (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
                           -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
                           -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                           -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                    END) END) END) END) AS CalculatedDays
```

Comment: This is the case statement to work out the number of working days(Public Holidays not catered for) and not the entire query.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
declare @StartDate date = '2016-03-21',
    @EndDate   date = '2016-03-25'

; with tbl (ProjectStartDate , ProjectEndDate) as
(
    select  '2016-03-13', '2016-03-22' union all
    select  '2016-03-22', '2016-03-29' union all
    select  '2016-03-13', '2016-03-29' 
)
select  *,
    [working days] = datediff(  day, 
                    case when ProjectStartDate > @StartDate then ProjectStartDate else @StartDate end, 
                    case when ProjectEndDate   < @EndDate   then ProjectEndDate   else @EndDate   end 
                 ) + 1
from    tbl
```